# How to use arc4random_uniform to randomly select a value from an array

Tags: swift

I have an array with a few values that I'd like to select a value from randomly but I'm having some trouble with the execution. I'm new to Swift so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

```
let types = ["value1", "value2", "value3"]

class someClass {
    let type = String(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(types)))
}
```

With this code, I get the error `Playground execution failed: <EXPR>:39:16: error: cannot invoke 'init' with an argument of type 'UInt32'
    let type = String(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(types)))
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~`

I tried something a little different to see if I could workaround this error.

```
let types = ["value1", "value2", "value3"]

class someClass {
    let x = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(4))
    let type = types[x]
}
```

But then I get this error: `Playground execution failed: <EXPR>:39:22: error: 'BlogPost.Type' does not have a member named 'x'
    let type = types[x]
                     ^`

I've only been working with Swift for a month so far so I'd definitely appreciate it if you guys could share your insight on both of the methods I tried, and if both methods are correctable how would you rework the code for both examples to make it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how you can do it:

```
let types = ["value1", "value2", "value3"]
let type = types[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(types.count)))]
println(type)
```

- The cast of `count` to `UInt32` is necessary because `arc4random_uniform` takes an unsigned value
- The cast of `arc4random_uniform` back to `Int` is required because array subscript operator `[]` takes an `Int`.

[Demo](http://www.runswiftlang.com/s/ZZ8lO-9c) (click [Compile] at the bottom to run).